# Increase the stack size of Application in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

I want to increase the stack size of an ipad application to 16MB .I have done it in xcode build setting "-WI-stack_size 1000000 to the Other Linker Flags field ".
but getting build error of 
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: stack_size: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: 1000000: No such file or directory

How can i resolve that ?

Answer (score 1):

Do not know if you got it solved or not, but the correct way to indicate such option to the linker (according to [this site](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1419/_index.html))  is to add `-Wl,-stack_size,1000000` to the **Other Linker Flags** field of the **Build Styles** pane. You are missing the commas.

In case you are using clang or gcc the cli would be:

```sh
g++ -Wl,-stack_size -Wl,1000000
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: For iOS, works well when deploying directly on device from XCode but unfortunately doesn't seem to survive the archiving phase :/

Answer (score -3):

If you think you need to increase the stack size you're almost certainly doing something very wrong in your code, like allocating way too large objects on the stack (ie a 16 MByte C array).

Instead, allocate the memory or use the proper Objective-C data structures (ie NSMutableArray).

Comment: There are legitimate reasons during testing you might want to increase the stack size.
So a downvote you will receive.